# Can't execute .bat files for locked folder

Tags: batch-file, network-programming

I've recently followed the online tutorial on creating hidden folders through a .bat file (essentially copy and pasted the code in the tutorial) and it works great on my local disk, but now I want that to sit on the network server and access the .bat unlock from there, but it tells me access is denied. Is this because it seems to be pulling from the control panel(it reads "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}") in the code) and therefor can't be on a "network" drive? Can i change that part of the code to make it accessible through the network? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jon, interesting question! If you could include the relevant batch script I'm sure people can better answer you. It could be code, it could be specific to the networked storage and it's file system type. If you could update the question with the network storage type e.g.NAS, Linux box, another windows machine etc... That'd go a ways into solving the problem.

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE], then update your question.

Comment: @DanielLane , thank you for responding! I apologize for the delay. Below is the code I used in reference to the question above.

Comment: The storage type is an other windows machine. I can't seem to share the code on here without exceeding the character limit. (clearly I'm new to all this). Below is the snippet of code from the top of the file.
cls
title Folder Test_Hidden_Folder
if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK
if NOT EXIST Test_Hidden_Folder goto MDTest_Hidden_Folder
:CONFIRM

Has this helped my question at all?